# Pulleys vs gears for a gravity battery

Tags: gears, pulleys, energy-storage

I would like to build a simple homemade [gravity battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_battery) (a weight is pulled to a high height and is then dropped to turn a motor and generate electricity.) My plan is to have a 5kg weight pulled to 2 meters, testing this example and then increasing the weight to 10kg and height to 4 meters.

I was originally thinking of using a gearbox of some sort, in order to reduce the height required to drop the weight, and increasing the RPM at which the motor-generator rotates (due to many motors I’ve found needing between 100-2000 rpm.)
After reading a related [post on this site](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44831/using-a-manual-pulley-system-to-repeatedly-lift-a-rock-and-gather-its-falling-en) about using pulleys to lift a weight, though, it has made me consider whether pulleys would be a better fit.

TL;DR - Would using pulleys, a gearbox, or a combination of the two be beneficial in decreasing the rope used when lifting/lowering a weight and increasing the RPM of the motor-generator?

Comment: Gears: no slip but friction. Pulleys can have both slip and friction.

Comment: @SolarMike If the rope was chain or rope with holes, so that slipping could be reduced?

Comment: Why I put "can".

Comment: That's a fun project. Remember that if the electrical load gets disconnected the weight will crash to the ground and the motor may over-speed. Some sort of over-voltage limiter might be a good idea.

Comment: @Transistor Good point! I was going to have a solenoid that would lock the wire in place when not needed

Comment: @SolarMike With regards to having slip, there are timing pulleys.

Comment: Have you not considered using sands or water instead? Real, *workable* gravity batteries use this method,  rather than dropping discrete weights (like that Energy Vault proposal).

Comment: @DKNguyen sure, but what's the cost of the matching toothed belt in 4 metre or 10 metre length compared to relatively simple rope?

Comment: @DKNguyen I was planning on using either river or rain water as a weight

Comment: Warning:  the total potential energy storage depends on the height to which you raise the weight, and nothing else, so you can't reduce the vertical dimension regardless of gearbox design.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I had assumed OP wanted gears to match the load characterostics to match the generator, but maybe not.

Comment: @DKNguyen  good point.

Comment: @DKNguyen You are correct, that is the set up I was planning to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient power transmission is chain and sprockets. These work very well at a nominal cost.

Gears are probably next, but at a higher cost due to gear fabrication.  The closed nature of a gear box should help longevity.  Be sure you have gears that run both ways if you're planning on lifting with the gear set - some don't, like worm gears.

Belted pulleys would be next, just a little less efficient.  This seems like it would be hard to manage, belts are generally continuous, though I guess they can be bought in length.  Pulleys with ropes will be last due to rope friction, but are probably the cheapest option here.

All the above will be affected by the bearings used, simple bushings will be less efficient than good quality roller bearings.

Comment: Yep, plus you can get chain+sprockets cheap from a bicycle salvage pile :-)

Comment: Gears can be 3d printed for cheap these days.